# Populating Subreports values using Java Object

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a List of Object. Below is the example of values in the List of Objects.

```
A X
A Y
A Z
B P 
B Q
B R
```

Meaning the values X,Y,Z are under group A and P,Q,R are under the group B.
Thru iReports i am able to list the values in the object (as above).

What i am trying to do is i want to display rows in grouped fashion in the reports .like below.

```
A
    X
    Y
    Z
B
    P
    Q
    R
```

I know it can be done in subreports. But i don't know how to do it thru the list of object what i have currently. Please suggest any idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At your subreport you can add a condition, in which, if an object has a first value X (a value passed as a param to the subreport), it will be written, and otherwise ignored.

Then, at the main report you can invoke the subreport once for every group, passing the key value and the full collection of objects.

Comment: Is there any builtin property available for the main report you can invoke the subreport once for every group. or do we need to do from bean (java) ?

Comment: I think you can define your own custom parameter, to be used at the subreport, and set a different value at the include from the main report. But I can't tell you the exact implementation.